# ImportError: No module named isodate

Tags: python, python-2.7

I cant import rdflib in python. error detailed:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 27 2012, 23:48:21) 
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rdflib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib/__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    from rdflib.term import URIRef, BNode, Literal, Variable
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rdflib/term.py", line 49, in <module>
    from isodate import parse_time, parse_date, parse_datetime
ImportError: No module named isodate
```

I would be grateful if anybody can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you actually install rdflib via `pip`, then its dependencies will come along with it (isodate included):

```
pip install -U rdflib
```

or

```
easy_install -U rdflib
```

Chances are you might have installed it directly from source, meaning you would have to take care of the deps yourself.

Information on installing pip if you dont have it already:
http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html

If you have easy_install, you can do: `easy_install pip`

Comment: Well, wouldn't *easy_install* install the deps as well? ;)

Comment: @NiklasR: Yea true. I just like to recommend pip I suppose ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but still have same problem.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Because easy_install/pip do load the dependencies. Completely remove all traces of this package from your python paths, and do a fresh `-U` installation. Otherwise, just install isodate: `easy_install -U isodate`

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is a dependency to [isodate](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/isodate/), so try installing that via your favorite PyPI-Installer (*pip* oder *easy_install*).

Comment: Thanks, but still have same problem.